# blowing-up under restriction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, and let $Y\subset X$ be any irreducible closed subvariety. Assume that $\mathcal{I}\subset \mathcal{O}_X$ is a coherent ideal sheaf such that $Y\not\subset{\rm Supp}(\mathcal{I})$. Define the blowing-up (in the analytic setting, such that $\widehat{X}$ is reduced)
$$\widehat{X}:={\rm Bl}_{\mathcal{I}}(X)\xrightarrow{\mu}X\ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \mathcal{O}_{\hat{X}}(-F)=\mu^*\mathcal{I}. $$
Set $\hat{Y}$ to be the strict transform of $Y$ under $\mu$, with $F_Y:=\hat{Y}\cap F$.

Question 1: Is the restriction $\mu|_Y:\hat{Y}\rightarrow Y$ the blowing-up of the coherent ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}|_Y$? i.e.,
 $$\hat{Y}={\rm Bl}_{\mathcal{I}|_Y}(Y)\xrightarrow{\nu}Y\ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \mathcal{O}_{\hat{Y}}(-F_Y)=\mu|_Y^*(\mathcal{I}|_Y).$$

Question 2: Set $p:\mathcal{Z}\rightarrow S$ be a smooth family parametrizing closed smooth irreducible subvarieities in $X$, with $S$ an affine variety.  Assume that for each fiber $Z_s:=p^{-1}(s)$, $Z_s\not\subset{\rm Supp}(\mathcal{I})$. Let $\widehat{\mathcal{Z}}$ be the strict transform under the morphism $\mu\times {\rm id}:\widehat{X}\times S\rightarrow X\times S$. Then for each fiber $\widehat{Z}_s:=(p\circ \mu\times {\rm id})^{-1}(s)$ of the fibration $\widehat{\mathcal{Z}}\rightarrow S$, is the map $\widehat{Z}_s\rightarrow Z_s$ nothing but the blowing-up of the ideal ${\rm Bl}_{\mathcal{I}|_{Z_s}}(Z_s)\rightarrow Z_s$?

Comment: This is Hartshorne Corollary II.7.15?

Comment: @ Chen Jiang: thanks! No problem for Question 1.  But for families, maybe question 2 is not true?